# Multiple loops issue in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Sorry for asking really basic question but I am confused in multiple loops.

I want to run loops all at same time and then break the loop and go to next loop for `R, e and x` combine.

```
Means for R =1 ,e=1 ,x=1 and then R=2 ,e=2 ,x=2 and so on.
```

Can someone tell me where I am at fault or what is missing to get my desired results?

Code:

```
 threshold = [0.4:0.1:1.1];       
 limit_for_idx  = [0.4:0.1:1.1]; 
 limit = [0.4:0.1:1.1];            


 D=1;
 E=1;
 J=0;
  for R = 1:numel(threshold);  
      for e = 1:numel(limit_for_idx);
          for x = 1:numel(limit)

          J = J+1 ;
          % Perform Tasks and go to next loop for R ,e and x           
          break
      end
        break
    end
  end
```

Comment: `break` exits the loop, so in effect in your code the inner loops only run once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong in your code is that in the 2nd iteration and so on, `e` and `x` will get `1` again, and not `2` or which value that you want.

To solve that, just iterate one variable and equal them all to it:

```
threshold = [0.4:0.1:1.1];       
limit_for_idx  = [0.4:0.1:1.1]; 
limit = [0.4:0.1:1.1];            
D=1;
E=1;
J=0;
for R=1:numel(threshold)
   e=R;
   x=R;
   % do your stuff...
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot it solved my issue . Thanks once again.